# Metric Tensor Antisymmetry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

The metric tensor on a Riemannian manifold is given as a symmetric $n \times n$ symmetric matrix (so $g_{ij} = g_{ji}$). Is there an intrinsic reason for this symmetry? Why can't it be antisymmetric (so $g_{ij} = -g_{ji}$), and what would be the physical meaning of the antisymmetry?

Comment: Well, if were anysymmtric then it could not be positive define, and then you'd have tangent vector of negative length.

Comment: Would that hold for non-Riemannian manifolds?

Comment: Non-riemannian manifolds have symmetric non-positive definite metrics.

Comment: So there's no escaping the symmetry?

Comment: Notice that symplectic manifolds are pretty much what you are after, but they are of a distinctly different flavour than riemanian ones.

Comment: Yep, those are pretty different! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be very general. Assume we are taking the metric tensor of the given point $g = g_{ij}(x)$. Assume everything in arbitrary coordinate system. Assume $M$ to be a arbitrary differentiable manifold, for an arbitrarily given metric tensor $g$.

For a given vector x, y:
$$
x\cdot y = g_{ij}(x)x^i y^j
$$

For a commutative inner product of vectors implies a symmetric metric tensor:
$$
x\cdot y = g_{ij}x^i y^j = g_{ij}x^j y^i = g_{ji}x^i y^j = g_{ji}x^j y^i = y\cdot x
$$

This implies: $ g_{ij} = g_{ji}$. Also very important:
$$
|x|^2 = g_{ij}x^i x^j = g_{ij}x^j x^i = g_{ji}x^i x^j = g_{ji}x^j x^i,
\quad\forall x\in M 
$$

The symmetric property is so important that some times the metric tensor is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Definition) to be this way.